# How to close connection with the azure service bus queue?

Tags: python, azure, azure-servicebus-queues

I am able to receive the message [from azure queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-queue/azure.storage.queue.queueclient?view=azure-python#receive-messages---kwargs-) using their official SDK. It works fine. Here is the snippet that I am using to receive a message from the queue.

```
   from azure.servicebus import QueueClient

   client = QueueClient.from_connection_string(
           q_string,
           q_name)

    msg = None

    with client.get_receiver() as queue_receiver:
        messages = queue_receiver.fetch_next(max_batch_size=1, timeout=3)
        if len(messages) > 0:
            msg = messages[0]
            print(f"Received {msg.message}")

    return msg
```

How do I close the connection with the queue? How can I do that? Is there any function available with azure sdk?

Comment: The link you shared is for storage queues and not service bus queues.

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS Updated the tag. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks but I still think that you're using Service Bus Queues and not Storage Queues. See the first line of code: `from azure.servicebus import QueueClient` :).

Comment: @GauravMantri-AIS Actually yes, re-edited the tag! I am not sure of the difference between the two :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I close the connection with the queue? How can I do that? Is
>   there any function available with azure sdk?

You can call [`close`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/azure-servicebus/azure/servicebus/_servicebus_client.py#L88) method on the service bus client. That will close down the Service Bus client and the underlying connection.

Comment: Okay. What does it mean to create a new receiver? If I have to poll the queue, does it degrade the performance if I create a receiver every `n` seconds?

Comment: Please see my comment. I think you're using Service Bus and not Storage Queues. Can you please confirm?

Comment: Yeah  I am using service bus .. `from azure.servicebus import QueueClient`

Comment: Does the performance get degraded if I create a new receiver every few seconds?

Comment: Updated my answer for Service Bus. HTH.

Comment: Could not understand its usage. Could you please give an example with the snippet I added in my question?

Comment: Would you know this?

Comment: Would you be able to answer a related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61927623/how-to-poll-the-azure-service-bus-queue-for-messages